# should python module, intended to be imported, call any function directly?

Tags: python

Lets have 
somemodule.py:

```
def func():
   pass

func()
```

And main script.py:

```
import somemodule

do_some_stuff()
```

Or 
somemodule.py:

```
class Myclass:
    def func():
        pass

obj = Myclass()
```

script.py

```
import somemodule

use_that_object(somemodule.obj)
```

I'm asking about general design and it's possible flaws.

Answer (score 2):

Your module will be imported only once, so any code in it, like function calls will be executed once.
If it's initialisation code for your module this is probably what you want.
I see no flaw in that.

Comment: This is a grey area, but IMHO importing should have no side-effects beyond making code available. Creating singletons or setting up some data-structures is ok, but starting threads, launching heavy processing and similar things are code-smells. This makes stuff harder to debug, and to test (harder to use e.g. mock or mox to mock away the module contents)

Comment: I agree, but with the added caveat that tools such as multiprocessing (on windows), documentation extractors, unit test frameworks and etc... may want to import your module for their own purposes without nasty side effects. You can initialize and call functions, but be judicious in what you do.